# Como pegar varios elementos e jogar em um unico item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ola, queria saber como posso pegar esses `li's` todos e colocar somente no primeiro `<ul>`.

```
<ul>
    <li>1 </li>
    <li>2 </li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4 </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>5 </li>
    <li>6 </li>
    <li>7 </li>
    <li>8 </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>9 </li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Queres apagar os outros ul?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('li').appendTo('ul:first');
```

Desse modo deixas os outros `ul` vazios.

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/dmymq4vo/

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio sua resposta se enquadrou mais no que eu precisava então vou marcar como correta ok.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('li').each(function(){
        $('.nova-ul').append($(this));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li>1 </li>
        <li>2 </li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4 </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>5 </li>
        <li>6 </li>
        <li>7 </li>
        <li>8 </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>9 </li>
        <li>10</li>
    </ul>

<ul class="nova-ul"></ul>
```

Mas, tal como o @Sergio perguntou e bem se quiser apagar os `<ul>` originais terá de acrescentar `$('ul').not('.nova-ul').remove();` depois do ciclo `each`